# Remote notification in .vue from other js file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have the following problem, I want to display a notification to my page, and I want to do it from a file that is in another folder

From here I would like to display it:

```js
putSucursal ({ dispatch }, sucursal) {
    http.put('/sucursales/' + sucursal.hash, sucursal).then(res => {
      dispatch('getSucursales')
      alert(res.data.message)
      router.push({ name: 'sucursales-admin' })
    }, err => {
      console.table(err)
      alert(err.message)
    })
  },
```

This is the other function in the other file, where I call it:

```js
postSucursal () {
  this.$store.dispatch('postSucursal', this.sucursal)
},
```

Try this, but it doesn't work:
https://github.com/euvl/vue-notification

Comment: In your file (which I'm guessing is not a `.vue` file, but a `.js` one?) you may need to `import Vue from 'vue';` and use `Vue.notify()` instead of `this.$notify()`. But if you don't post any code related to that, there is no way we can be sure what you're doing wrong. I'm voting to close this question until it contains [enough details to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)